# $\sum _1 ^n |z_j| \ge 1 \Rightarrow | \sum _1 ^k z_{j_m}| \ge C$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, summation, estimation

Prove that there exists $C > 0$ such that the following implication holds:

If $\{z_1, ..., z_n \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ are such that $\sum _{j=1} ^n |z_j| \ge 1$,

then there exists $ \{z_{j_1}, ..., z_{j_k} \} \subset \{z_1, ..., z_n \}$ such that $ |\sum _{m=1} ^k z_{j_m}| \ge C$

What is the value of $C$?

Could you help me deal with this problem?

I'll be grateful for all your hints.

Comment: Of course, I'll corect it right away.

Comment: Presumably $C$ must be positive, as $C=0$ works just fine. As well, what prevents you from choosing *any* $z_j$? I mean, $|\sum_{m=1}^1z_m|\geq |z_m|$. So there are some conditions missing to this problem. Is it that any subset satisfies the inequality with $C$?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, for the optimum value $C$ is 
$$
C=\frac{1}{\pi}.
$$
This is Lemma 6.3, page 118, in W. Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. This was first proved by Kaufmann and Rickert in [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., **72**, p. 672-676, 1966.](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-04/S0002-9904-1966-11551-3/home.html)

Comment: I have one question about the proof in Rudin's book. He writes there that $z_k = |z_k| e^{i \alpha_k}$ and for $\phi \in [- \pi, \pi], \ \ S(\phi):= \{ k | \cos (\alpha_k - \phi)>0 \}$. Then $|\sum _{S(\phi)} z_k| = |\sum_{S(\phi) } e^{-i \phi} z_k|$. Could you tell me why those two sums are equal?